# Setting margin:auto on inline-flex container doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I want  to center an inline-flex container inside of parent div, but setting *margin:auto* doesn't do anything even though the parent div is wider than the flex container. (as you can see from the result)

*Setting justify-content to center doesn't give the wanted result.*

I tried to set *display:inline-flex* in the css to see if it was a Bootstrap issue, but no go.

I've set the background-color's to visualize the object's.

**Html**:

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block" style="background-color:blue;">
    <div class="d-inline-flex flex-wrap lc-product-thumb-wrap">
        <img src="demo1.png" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-0" />
        <img src="demo1.png" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-1" />
        <img src="demo2.png" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-2" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.lc-product-thumb-wrap {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

.lc-product-thumb-wrap .lc-product-thumb-img {
  width: 98px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #003c02;
  background-color: #dafac1;
}
```

**Result**:
[image]

Comment: `margin: auto` works on block elements. Now with `inline-flex` the clue should be kinda in the name ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it's inline element, `margin:auto` won't work, use `text-align:center;` to `.d-md-block`.

```css
.d-md-block {
  text-align: center;
}

.lc-product-thumb-wrap {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: auto;
}

.lc-product-thumb-wrap .lc-product-thumb-img {
  width: 98px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #003c02;
  background-color: #dafac1;
}
```

```html
<div class="d-none d-md-block" style="background-color:blue;">
  <div class="d-inline-flex flex-wrap lc-product-thumb-wrap">
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-0" />
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-1" />
    <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=28&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300" class="lc-product-thumb-img" id="thumb-2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the asker was thinking of `margin: auto` in a flex context, then it doesn't work because the parent is not a flex container, not because it is an inline-level element (which, incidentally, it wouldn't be, if the parent were a flex container, since flex items automatically become block-level elements).

Comment: @Michael_B: The parent div is a .d-md-block, so it's safe to assume it's not a flex container.

Comment: @BoltClock, yes, I saw that. But since the question was about `margin: auto`, which is normally not used for centering in a block formatting context -- it's usually `margin: 0 auto`, and [`margin: auto` doesn't even work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34552116/3597276) -- I figured that the asker was thinking in terms of a flex formatting context, where [`margin: auto` does center vertically and horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34552444/3597276).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer.

A very simple way to do this is by adding `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements on the `inline-flex` element and adding `flex: 1;` to them.

Those two pseudo-elements will take up the available space remaining and will have no `width` when there is none.

`.lc-product-thumb-wrap`  below, is the class of the `inline-flex` element

```css
.lc-product-thumb-wrap {
  width: 100%;
}

.lc-product-thumb-wrap:before,
.lc-product-thumb-wrap:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}
```